# Transiting via Madrid to Venice

Tags: schengen, transit, uk-citizens, new-zealand-citizens, mad

I have e mailed Iberia but not had a reply. Can anyone please tell me if i book a flight Malaga to Venice and choose one with 6 plus hours transit in Madrid, therefore our bags are not our care, can we exit the airport ok for this time?

We will have UK / NZ passports

Answer (score 2):

I do not even understand why this is a question. Obviously yes and the airline has absolutely nothing to do with it. If you are starting from Malaga you are legally admitted to Spain already so why on earth would you not be able to leave the airport to another Spanish city? (not to mention that Venice is in the Schengen area too, but that's irrelevant)

It'd be an intriguing historical question whether in the Soviet Union in a similar situation this would've been allowed but in today's Spain, this is not a question.

Comment: It may well NOT be  a question in Spain - but your regional knowledge presumably tells you that. In other countries it may not be so obvious. Last year in Delhi I entered the local terminal building for a flight to Pune. I wished to leave the building to take a specific photo outside. One of the significant number of very polite very friendly men in Army uniforms and carrying large automatic weapons informed me that regrettably, once I was inside I had to stay inside. I understand the reasons in that case. Hopefully in Spain such things would not be relevant.

Comment: FWIW - what I wanted to photograph (although I did not say so) was the small (3m square?) concrete building half way up the curving access ramp, that had large glassless slot windows. As we drove past and too fast for my reactions I had noted that the interior was wholly lined with sandbags - a machine-gun nest (presumably at that stage unmanned) with protection against concrete spalling when under fire.  I asssume that the refusal of exit permission related to what might be in the checked in bags of anyone who left the terminal :-(. Spain is not totally free of such history, as you know.

Comment: There are still millions of people out there who have no idea what the Schengen area is or how it works.

Comment: Frankly I don't see the need for that initial comment: `I do not even understand why this is a question.`. For starters people have doubts and questions: it's normal. Moreover this site was created to answer questions. You could therefore apply the same reasoning to all 10k+ posts on the site and just shut it down.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things here to be aware of.   You are arriving in the Schengen area in Madrid and will have to clear Spanish / EU passports immigration in Madrid

http://www.aena.es/csee/Satellite/Aeropuerto-Madrid-Barajas/en/Page/1237565045453//Arrivals.html

This may mean a significant proportion of time waiting at immigration

I would also reconfirm with your that your baggage will be checked through, as I believed that if you are clearing immigration in Spain, you also had to clear customs. The flight connections page

http://www.aena.es/csee/Satellite/Aeropuerto-Madrid-Barajas/en/Page/1237565034728//Flight-connections.html

Suggests that connection with luggage are made at the baggage reclaim hall.  I think you then immediately re deposit your luggage at the flight connections desk

You will need to ensure that you have boarding passes issued for the Madrid Venice segment, if you do not have these as print at home documents you may have to collect these at Madrid from the airline transfer desk.

You will need these to re enter the security controlled area at Madrid, there are often queues for this at madrid.

The airport website suggested time to clear security and get to gates for the EU leg is 120 mins

http://www.aena.es/csee/Satellite/Aeropuerto-Madrid-Barajas/en/Page/1237565036782//Departures.html#Security%20checks

Hope this helps

Comment: Madrid to Venice is an international connection even though it is within the Schengen area, so it is also likely that the luggage is checked through and the passengers leaving the airport just to sight see just walk through customs with that part of their hand luggage they do not want to leave in a locker in the secure part of the airport.